# How to compare 2 arrays with unequal numbers of elements in Excel

Tags: excel, array-formulas

In an Excel array formula, I would like to test each element of one array against each element of a second array, when the 2 arrays do NOT have the same number of elements. Simplified right down, this scenario could be represented by:

=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2})

NB - in my real world scenario these arrays are calculated from various prior steps.

Using the above example, I would want a result of {TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}. What I get is {TRUE,TRUE,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A}.

It's clear that, when there's more than 1 value being tested for, Excel wants equal numbers of elements in the 2 arrays; when there isn't, the #N/A error fills in the blanks.

I've considered writing a UDF to achieve what I want, and I'm pretty sure my coding skills are up to creating something like:

=ArrayCompare({1,2,3,4,5},"=",{1,2})

But I'd much rather do this using native functionality if it's not too cumbersome...

So, simple question; can an array formula be constructed to do what I'm after?

Thanks peeps!

Comment: Presumably you want the "missing" numbers in the shorter array to assume a zero value?

Comment: Would something like this work? `=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2},TRUE),FALSE)`

Comment: @chancea - that has the same problem in that it wants both arrays to be the same size

Comment: @TimWilliams I just ran both your answer and my code and got the same output....

Comment: yep that does work, for 'equals' (and which I put in my example)! cheers chancea! but my example was too easy... I haven't been able to get this to work for 'not equal'... any ideas?

Comment: so, =SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3,4,5}<>{1,2}) should produce {FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}

Comment: I turned things round... IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}<>{1,2},FALSE),TRUE)

Comment: it seems there might not be one single way of covering all comparison types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second array is a subset of the first array, same order, and starting at position 1 then you can use this array formula for equivalence testing:

```
=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2},TRUE),FALSE)
```

For non equivalence just swap the `FALSE` and `TRUE`

```
=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2},FALSE),TRUE)
```

You can then use this in other formulas just as an array:

[image]

However if the arrays are not in order, as in this example:

```
{1,2,3,4,5},{1,4,5}
```

Then you have to use `MATCH`.  However all you need is to surround the match with an `ISNUMBER` like so:

Equivalence test:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5},{1,4,5},0))
```

Non Equivalence test:

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5},{1,4,5},0)))
```

[image]
*Remember all array formulas are entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>*

Comment: Perfect chancea! Cheers :)

Comment: Very interesting... I am seeing the same values for both `=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2},FALSE),TRUE)` and `=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}<>{1,2},FALSE),TRUE)` I must ponder this

Comment: If I do this `=IFERROR(IF({5,2,3,4,1}={1,2},TRUE),FALSE)`  (ie switch the 1 and 5 in the first array) I get `FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: ...but I guess that doesn't matter if your arrays are always in the same order and the second one is always a right-truncated version of the first?

Comment: @TimWilliams and @WilliamBell I am completely wrong.  `=IFERROR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}={1,2},TRUE),FALSE)`  Only works because the first two elements of `{1,2,3,4,5}` line up with `{1,2}` the only way to be sure is to use the `MATCH` function as you shown.  You should update your post with the non equivalent case and that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using `MATCH` function is probably the best way.....but if you actually want to compare every element in one array with another array in a direct comparison then one should be a "column" and one a "row", e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(({1,2,3,4,5}={1;4})+0)`

Note the semi-colon separator in the second array

If you can't actually change the column/row designation then `TRANSPOSE` can be used, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT(({1,2,3,4,5}=TRANSPOSE({1,4}))+0)`

You may not get the required results if the arrays contain duplicates because then you will get some double-counting, e.g. with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(({1,1,1,1,1}={1;1})+0)`

the result is 10 because there are 5x2 comparisons and they are all TRUE

Comment: hi barry, cheers for suggesting this! while it doesn't help me directly, due to the complexity of what follows in my spreadsheet, it's a very useful addition to this question that could help others struggling with array manipulation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5},{1,2},0)),FALSE,TRUE)}
```

Comment: hi Tim. thanks for your idea! chancea's IFERROR approach is a tad shorter though... :)

Comment: This is the appropriate answer over mine as I noted in my comments earlier.  And not that it matters that much but this could be shortened to `=ISNUMBER(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5},{1,2},0))` for equivalence and `=NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5},{1,2},0)))` for non equivalence